# How can I use Coolpro music editor on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying out Ubuntu.  I have been using a music editor named Coolpro.  I have the installation disk for it.  Can I install it into my computer that is running Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the Coolpro program support linux?

Comment: @kjones I tried doing a google search, it brought up results for a program called `Cool Edit Pro` which has been renamed to Adobe Audition. I don't think that Adobe make linux programs, plus I couldn't find anything on their website

Comment: Do you mean Cool Edit Pro? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Audition http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/audition.html ? windows only and non-free... Please give some information about the software. Otherwise, generic answer [How can I install Windows software or games?](//askubuntu.com/q/988)

Answer (score 1):

If the software doesn't natively support Linux it's possible get it working using WINE. It's not perfect, but you could try running it and see how it works.

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu